# Gnuplot - generate a random number to use random style?

Tags: gnuplot

I am looking for a way to generate a random number, so I can use it to assign an arbitrary style or color to a line.

I have a function that I call, which load a settings file; the function read a file, and plot data. In the settings file I have set different styles for the line color, width and style. I use shell scripting as language.

The idea is that instead of calling

```
plot 'filename' using 1 with linespoints ls 1....2...3....n
```

I can do something like

```
plot 'filename' using 1 with linespoints ls [random number]
```

I know how to calculate a random number with gnuplot; so to get a number between 1-15 I do

```
15*(rand(0))
```

Can I use this as source for the random number in the plot command, so it will look like

```
plot 'filename' using 1 with linespoints ls 15*(rand(0))
```

Or there is a better/more correct way to do so?
I could even generate the number outside gnuplot; just trying to learn how to do all in gnuplot, but I am open to other solution. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that approach works, doesn't it? So what would be `more correct`?

Comment: For the sake of learning how to do things in the right way; I rely on the expertise of others, that can tell me a better way to accomplish the same thing. The fact that my approach works, is not necessarily a sign that is a well done job, don't you think?

Comment: You are right. The only little improvement I see is to explicitely convert the random number to an integer. The `int` function effectively drops the decimal part, so if you need linestyles `1-15` you must add 1: `plot x w lp lt int(15*rand(0))+1`.